# Ruby RegEx to locate image assets in an html/erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

My end goal is to write a script that will loop through all my app/views folders and find any image assets being used within them (jpg, png, svg, gifs) and I can't *quite* get it but I feel I am close but need a little assistance.

**This is how I am getting all my assets**

```
assets_in_assets = []
# I searched for image asset names in this folder
image_asset_path = './app/assets/images'
# I haven't made use the below global variables yet
assets_in_use = []
# I plan to loop through the below folders to see if and where the image 
# assets are being used
public_folder = './public'
app_folder = './app'

Find.find(image_asset_path) do |path|
# returns path and file names of all files extensions recursively
  if !File.directory?(path) && path =~ /.*[\.jpg$ | \.png$ | .svg$ | \.gif$]/ 
   && !(path =~ /\.DS_Store/)
    new_path = File.basename(path) # equiv to path.to_s.split('/').last
    assets_in_assets << new_path
  end
end
# The above seems to work, it gives me all the asset image names in an array.
```

**This is how i am *trying* read a html.erb file to find if and where images are being used.**

Here is a sample of part of the page:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content-wrapper pull-center center-text">
    <img class="pattern-stars" src="<%= image_path('v3/super/pattern-
     stars.png') %>" aria-hidden="true">

    <h2 class="pull-center uppercase">Built by the Obsessed People at the
     Company</h2>
    <p class="top-mini">Our pets needed a challenge.</p>
    <p class="italicize">So we made one.</p>
    <img class="stroke" src="<%= image_path('v3/super/stroke.png') %>" 
     aria-hidden="true">
  </div>
</div>

# The assets I am  expecting to find, in this small section,  are:
 #- pattern-stars.png
 #- stroke.png
```

And my code (I tried two different ways, here is the first):

```
# My plan is start with one specific file, then expand it once the code works
lines = File.open('./app/views/pages/chewer.html.erb', 'r')
lines.each do |f|
  if f =~ / [\w]+\.(jpe?g | png | gif | svg) /xi
    puts 'match: ' + f # just wanted to see what's being returned
  end
end

# This is what gets returned
# match: <img class="pattern-stars" src="<%= image_path('v3/super
# /pattern-stars.png') %>" aria-hidden="true">
# match: <img class="stroke" src="<%= image_path('v3/super/stroke.png') 
# %>" aria-hidden="true">
```

Not what I was hoping for. I also tried the following:

```
lines = File.open('./app/views/pages/chewer.html.erb', 'r')
 lines.each do |f|
  new_f = File.basename(f)
  puts 'after split' + new_f # I wanted to see what was being returned
  if new_f =~ / [\w]+\.(jpe?g | png | gif | svg) /xi
    puts 'match: ' + new_f
  end
end

# This is what gets returned
# after split: pattern-stars.png') %>" aria-hidden="true">
# match: pattern-stars.png') %>" aria-hidden="true">
# after split: stroke.png') %>" aria-hidden="true">
# match: stroke.png') %>" aria-hidden="true">
```

And here I remain blocked. I have searched through S.O. and tried a few things but nothing I have found has helped but it could be that I implemented the solutions incorrectly. I also tried look-behind (using the single ' as a end point) and look-ahead (using a / as a starting point)

If this is a dup or similar to another question, please let me know. I'd appreciate the help (plus an brief explanation, I really want to get a better understanding to improve my skills.

Comment: `f` is unchanged by `=~`; the matched string is in `$0`, and a `MatchData` object in `$~` (or equivalently, `Regexp.last_match`). `=~` might look like an assignment, but it isn't one. Thus, printing `f` merely prints the whole line where the match occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the above, I eventually got to the following solution;

```
Find.find(app_folder, public_folder) do |path|
  if !File.directory?(path) 
   && !(path =~/\.\/app\/assets\/images/) 
   && !(path =~ /\.DS_Store/) 
   && !(path =~ /\.\/app\/assets\/fonts/)
    asset_file = File.read(path)
    image_asset =  asset_file.scan(/ (?:['"|\s|@])([^'"|\s|@]+\.(?:png | jpe?g |gif | svg)) /xi).flatten
    image_asset.each do |image_name|
      assets_in_use << [path, File.basename(image_name)]
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`(?:['"])([^'"]+\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif|svg))` [seems to work](http://www.rubular.com/r/fixq2SuB67) in the one test case you supplied us. It relies on the image paths always being within a string as the 'this is the start of the image path' delimiter and terminates at the extension so even if the string is unclosed should stop at an appropriate place.